# How to fix form error 'validate' of undefined in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

***HTML***

```
 <form nz-form [formGroup]="formGroup">
        <nz-form-item>
          <nz-form-label nzFor="username">
            <span translate>Username</span>
          </nz-form-label>
          <nz-form-control nzHasFeedback>
            <input nz-input name="username" type="text" id="username" formControlName="username"
              [placeholder]="'Enter Username' | translate" (keydown.space)="$event.preventDefault()" />
            <nz-form-explain *ngIf="
              (formGroup.get('username')?.dirty && formGroup.get('username')?.errors) ||
              formGroup.get('username')?.pending
            ">
              <ng-container *ngIf="formGroup.get('username')?.hasError('required')">
                Username is required
              </ng-container>
              <ng-container *ngIf="formGroup.get('username')?.hasError('duplicated')">
                Username already exists. Please try different username
              </ng-container>
              <ng-container *ngIf="formGroup.get('username')?.pending">
                Validating...
              </ng-container>
            </nz-form-explain>
          </nz-form-control>
        </nz-form-item>
</form>
```

***TS****

```
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators, FormControl, ValidationErrors } from '@angular/forms';



 userNameAsyncValidator = (control: FormControl) =>
    new Observable((observer: Observer<ValidationErrors | null>) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        if (control.value === 'JasonWood') {
          observer.next({ error: true, duplicated: true });
        } else {
          observer.next(null);
        }
        observer.complete();
      }, 1000);
    });

  createFormGroup(data?: Partial<User>) {
    const dataObj = {
      id: [data && data.id],
      username: [
        {
          value: (data && data.username) || '',
          disabled: data instanceof User
        },
        [Validators.required], 
[this.userNameAsyncValidator]
      ]
    }

    return this.fb.group(dataObj);
}
```

***user.module***

```
imports: [
    CommonModule,
    UsersRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    PageTableFilterModule,
    CellRenderersModule,
    NzDrawerModule,
    NzFormModule,
    NzInputModule,
    NzSelectModule,
    NzDividerModule
    ]
```

how to fix the error: `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'validate' of undefined`.

What I want is username have a validation which is `already exists` and `username is required`.

I added the userNameAsyncValidator, after I added in username then it start causing an error which is the `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'validate' of undefined`. but when I try to remove the userNameAsyncValidator in username it doesn't have any error.

how to fix it?

ERROR:

````
    at normalizeAsyncValidator (forms.js:930)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at composeAsyncValidators (forms.js:2150)
    at coerceToAsyncValidator (forms.js:2501)
    at new FormControl (forms.js:3236)
    at FormBuilder.push../node_modules/@angular/forms/fesm5/forms.js.FormBuilder.control (forms.js:6462)
    at FormBuilder.push../node_modules/@angular/forms/fesm5/forms.js.FormBuilder._createControl (forms.js:6502)
    at forms.js:6488
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at FormBuilder.push../node_modules/@angular/forms/fesm5/forms.js.FormBuilder._reduceControls (forms.js:6487)```
````

Comment: Can you show imports in your TS file?!

Comment: @SakkeerA done sir. I added the imports also the user.module

Comment: Does this.userNameAsyncValidator validator getting triggered?

Comment: @Chellappanவ when I try to run this is the error ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'validate' of undefined

Comment: Can you remove this.userNameAsyncValidator from validators array and check?

Comment: @Chellappanவ I remove the this.userNameAsyncValidator the condition duplicate will not work and there will be no error.

Comment: @Chellappanவ I need to validate the username cause, when there's an existing username. the message will be ```<ng-container *ngIf="formGroup.get('username')?.hasError('duplicated')">
                Username already exists. Please try different username
              </ng-container>```

Answer (score 1):

Since this.userNameAsyncValidator is async validator add userNameAsyncValidator as third paramter to username control. another change is move your form creation inside ngOnInit or constructo like this:

**Try this:**

```
 constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.validateForm = this.createFormGroup();
  }

 createFormGroup(data?: Partial<User>) {
        const dataObj = {
          id: [data && data.id],
          username: [
            {
              value: (data && data.username) || '',
              disabled: data instanceof User
            },
            [Validators.required],
            [this.userNameAsyncValidator]
          ]
        }

        return this.fb.group(dataObj);
    }
```

Comment: You are injecting form builder inside contructor and trying to access form builder before it's get created if you move your form creation insde ngOnInit or contrctor it will not throw any error

Comment: I just comment the code on the constructor. inside my constructor is empty. have you fix it?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mcbdzg-ke8gcx?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 1):

In my case, when upgrading to Angular 11. The following validators array was breaking the unit tests:

```
[, Validators.required]
```

Notice there is nothing before the comma. Removing the comma fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case i had to remove FormsModule and ReactiveFormModule from imports to work